# Solve Database design about cards

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a card exchange project (TCG) that covers the multiple franchises that exist on one platform.

[image]

So far I have defined the series table here the different series that exist from TCG will be saved, such as pokemon, magic, yu gi oh etc ...

the card table where the card will obviously go, a collection table where the user can register the cards he has, the user table and the table where the proposed cards for the exchange will be kept and the user who changes it

my problem in this database model is that they manage to solve the exchange in a good way since, as shown in the image, a cycle occurs where the user password can be easily obtained through a sql query from the collection table

i tried to search references from databases where they can be exchanged but failed to find references.

Comment: You seem to confuse database design with security/authorization management. What is your real question? How to make a DB design that supports card exchanges?

Comment: how to make a DB design that supports card exchanges

Answer (score 0):

A card exchange is represented by a pair of [user_id, card_id] pairs such that before the exchange, card_id is in the collection of the user referenced with user_id, and after the exchange, it's in the collection of the other user.

Consequently, you should replace your `change` table with the following `card_exchanges` table:

```
card_exchanges(
  exchange_date,
  user1_id FK REF users, 
  card1_id FK REF cards,
  user2_id FK REF users, 
  card2_id FK REF cards
)
```

Notice that `card_exchanges` is not an *entity table*, but a transaction/*event table*.